# JS: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, styles

(Sorry for my aplogize, I got some mistake, just updated the new code again.)
I have the following code，and Chome throws"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" to the console：

```js
function gen_mainTable(){
var code = "";
code +='<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="center" class="FormTable_table" id="mainTable_table">';
code +='<tr><td class="CL">SELECT</td><br><td colspan="2" class="CR"><input type="radio" id="aa" name="type_group" value="0" onchange="change_mode();" checked>AA<input type="radio" id="bb" name="type_group" value="1" onchange="change_mode();" >BB</td></tr><br>';
code +='<tr id="aa_field" style="display:none"><td class="CL">TYPE_AA:
      </td><td colspan="2" class="CR"><input type="text" id="type_aa" name="type_aa" maxlength="15" size="20" value=""/></td></tr><br>';
code +='<tr id="bb_field"><td class="CL">TYPE_BB:</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="CR"><input type="text" id="type_bb" name="type_bb" maxlength="15" size="20" value=""/></td></tr>

$("mainTable").style.display = "";
$("mainTable").innerHTML = code;}
```

js part:

```js
function change_mode(){
  var mode = get_checked_value(get_by_name("type_group"));
  if (mode == "0"){
   get_by_id("aa_field").style.display = "";
   get_by_id("bb_field").style.display = "none";
   get_by_id("type_bb").disabled = true;
   get_by_id("type_aa").disabled = false;
  }else{
   get_by_id("aa_field").style.display = "none";
   get_by_id("bb_field").style.display = "";
   get_by_id("type_aa").disabled = true;
   get_by_id("type_bb").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

Update the "get_by_id" function:

```js
function get_by_id(id){
 with(document){
  return getElementById(id);
 }
}
```

I'll appreciate if anybody can help, thx :-)

Comment: one id might be not existing

Comment: where is get_by_id function defined in your javascript

Comment: What is `get_by_id`? You should add that code to your question.

Comment: I updated the "get_by_id" function, thx :-)!!!!

Comment: Where is your script placed above or below the html???

Comment: I use <script> tag placed my script.

Comment: Sorry I got some mistakes! Just updated the code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I learned something today: you can't grab a `tr` from a table using an id (either `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector`) if there are no `table` tags surrounding the row data.

See this demo. In the first instance I'm picking up the `bob` row because it's in some `table` tags, in the second `rose` is `null` because it isn't:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b0ffj2aj/29/)

So, to solve this, put `table` elements around your row data :)

It seems this is because [the HTML specification requires that a `tr` must live within either a `tfoot`, `thead`, `tbody` or `table` context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element) for it to "be acceptable" for inclusion in the DOM.